# Python pickle for Machine Learning

Tags: python

I have built a predictive model  in Windows to train the dataset using python 3.6.1. I have used pickle to save the train model as a Pickle file

Now I have written a another python script to read and load the train pickle file to predict the test data.

I have got results successful in Windows.

Now I want to move the Train pickle file and the Python script (that used the Train pickle file to predict the model using test data) to Linux environment which has the similar version of python installation as that of windows.But the python installation in Linux doesn't include machine learning libraries.

In such a case will the Train pickle file of windows behave as a exe file having all the machine learning libraries?

Will the python script that loads and read the train pickle file to predict the data fail in Linux as it does not any machine learning libraries installed.

Comment: A pickle file is just the serialized data of whatever object you happen to pickle. Any libraries will need to be installed in a new environment using pip. Depending on your timeframe for doing this, I would look into Docker containers and/or Bash scripts for replicating your local environment onto a server.

Comment: Why you are not installing the libraries in linux? Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

Pickling is just the python form of serialization.  Serialization only preserves raw data, such as strings, integers, floats, lists, and similar things.

If you pickle a model, you can unpickle it and use it later, but if you don't have the libraries (keras, tensorflow, or whatever you need), you cannot use it on that machine.

Comment: Thanks.Then what is best way to convert my python script as a executable file in Linux.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  I think you need to install the entire library, or host your model at an external URL.

Comment: You can look for a solution online, I don't think it's possible though.